# $scope variable is not evaluating in array push

Tags: angularjs

```
    $scope.aggregateInventory.push(
                {
                    profileValueDTOs: [{
                        propertyGroupName: $scope.profileValueDTOs.propertyGroupName,
                        propertyTypeName: $scope.profileValueDTOs.propertyTypeName,
                        profileCriteria: [$scope.profileCriteria]
                    }]
                });



$scope.$watch(
        function () {
            $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.aggregateInventory));
        }
    )
```

**Current out is:**

```
{
    "profileValueDTOs": [
        {
            "profileCriteria": [
                {
                    "comparisonOperator": "Contains",
                    "propertyElementName": "DeviceClass"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above angularjs code I am adding the scope variables to arraylist, which is resulting in below output.

**Expected output should be:**

```
{
    "profileValueDTOs": [
        {
            "propertyGroupName": "Test1",
            "propertyTypeName": "Test2",
            "profileCriteria": [
                {
                    "comparisonOperator": "Contains",
                    "propertyElementName": "DeviceClass"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Can someone help in getting the expected output?

Comment: Please add a plunkr or similar with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not using watch the correct way.
Remember that the first parameter of watch is a function that should **return WHAT we want to watch**, the second parameter is a function with the before and after values.

Also, you're not DEEP watching the array - adding a third parameter (true) will deep watch the array as well. Another way to do this is to use `$watchCollection`

Read more here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

And Here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection

Try the following code:

```
$scope.aggregateInventory.push(
                {
                    profileValueDTOs: [{
                        propertyGroupName: $scope.profileValueDTOs.propertyGroupName,
                        propertyTypeName: $scope.profileValueDTOs.propertyTypeName,
                        profileCriteria: [$scope.profileCriteria]
                    }]
                });



$scope.$watch(
        function () {
            return $scope.aggregateInventory;
        },
        function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $log.log('BEFORE:' + JSON.stringify(oldVal));
            $log.log('AFTER:' +JSON.stringify(newVal));
        },true

    )
```